# I'm unable to right-click my webpage in Chrome after including Angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a mock website that I'm working on as a proof of concept. I'm using a mixture of HTML5, Bootstrap, and AngularJS.

Everything was going well until I added some AngularJS code, then the right-click menu stopped working in Chrome. (I tested it and its working in IE.) Otherwise the page is working exactly as expected.

I've included the HTML and the Angular-related JS below. Any searches I can think to do for a solution bring up totally unrelated answers. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
Hello World
</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"> </script> <script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script> <script src="public/js/angular.min.js"> </script> <script src="public/js/dragdrop.js"> </script>
</head> <body data-ng-app="testapp" data-ng-controller="testappCtrl"> <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-2 ">
<img src="http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/i/2014/004/5/3/battle_power_sword_by_ittoogami-d70wvph.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
</img>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 ">
<div style="border: 5px solid" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
<p>
Name: 
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="name">
</p>
<p>
{{name}}
</p>
</div>
</div>
<script src="public/js/testapp.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('testapp', []);
app.controller('testappCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.name = "";
});
```

Comment: The dragdrop library and its associated inline event handlers are what draw my eye. You said it works so long as the angular bit is absent, though, so first question: what Angular version are you using?

Comment: also, I see two html errors: <DOCTYPE instead of <!DOCTYPE, and </img>. <img> is self-closing with or without a final /; it can't have a close tag. I think all browsers will just ignore invalid close tags, but to be safe you probably want to rule that out first.

Comment: I made the two changes that you suggested and its working now - I suspect it was the <DOCTYPE error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes to the  tags suggested by Semicolon and everything is working again.